# Sharing Session Socket.io Express

Tags: node.js, express, session, socket.io

I am using the `express-socket.io-session` and `express-mysql-session` to share a session between `socket.io` and `express`. I do this as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});

var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session');


var options = {
    host: "...",
    user: "...",
    password: "...",
    database: "...",
    };


var con = mysql.createConnection(options);

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({},con);

var session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "...",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store : sessionStore
});

var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

// Use express-session middleware for express
app.use(session);

// Use shared session middleware for socket.io
// setting autoSave:true
io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave:true
}));
```

Next, I have the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    console.log(req.session.sessionId);
    console.log(req.session.username);
});
```

Finally:

```
socket.on('login', function(data) {
     socket.handshake.session.sessionId = sessionId;
     socket.handshake.session.username = result[0].username;
     socket.handshake.session.save();
}
```

When I check my database, these values are saved correctly. However,

```
console.log(req.session.sessionId);
console.log(req.session.username);
```

always prints `undefined`, even after the login has occurred.

Comment: In `socket.handshake.session.sessionId = sessionId;`, where does `sessionId` come from?